# Customizing Ribbon in PowerPoint programmatically

Tags: vba, powerpoint

How to do it?

The old-style `CommandBars.Add` and `Controls.Add` are obsolete and the first is not working at all.

On the other hand, `SetCustomUI` doesn't seem to be there.

[This](https://blog.bvisual.net/2011/03/14/how-to-run-vba-macros-from-a-ribbon-button-in-visio-2010/) solution once worked very well for me, but I don't have Visio anymore and can't see the code. Would be nice, if someone could post the VBA code from the linked [vsd](https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=3350d61bc93733a9&resid=3350D61BC93733A9!2388&parid=3350D61BC93733A9!197).

Here is the attempt via Callback `getContent`

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub dynamicMenu_getContent(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef content)

    Dim RibbonXML As String

    Stop

    RibbonXML = "<menu xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui"">"
    RibbonXML = RibbonXML + "   <button id=""dynaButton"" label=""Button"" "
    RibbonXML = RibbonXML + "       onAction=""OnAction"" imageMso=""FoxPro""/>"
    RibbonXML = RibbonXML + "   <menuSeparator id=""div2""/>"
    RibbonXML = RibbonXML + "       <dynamicMenu id=""subMenu"" label=""Sub Menu"" getContent=""getContent"" />"
    RibbonXML = RibbonXML + "</menu>"

    content = RibbonXML

End Sub
```

Comment: With Ribbon XML there is no way to control the interface from a process running outside the application. The #2 you show is specific for *MS PROJECT* and doesn't apply to the "core" Office applications such as Word, Excel, PowerPoint and Access. These incorporate the Ribbon XML in their files or, in the case of a COM/VSTO Add-in it's loaded by the add-in in-process.

Comment: You'll find a list of useful documentation on Ribbon XML here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/ba8c9d0b-7312-4503-8167-f2ef86f17435/information-on-the-office-fluent-ui-ribbon-for-developers?forum=officegeneral I recommend you begin with the articles "Customize the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for developers"

Comment: Then you're asking in the wrong place. Stack Overflow is not a free code-writing or tutorial service.

Comment: Because there's no simple answer for your question. It can't be done with a few lines of code. There's no *object model* for Ribbon XML inside the Office application. Read that article I recommended and you'll understand what I'm saying.

Comment: The old command bar code still works (although with slightly different results) in PowerPoint 2007-2016.  When an add-in creates command bars, PPT adds a new Add-ins tab to the ribbon.  The buttons created by the commandbar code appear there.  There's example commandbar code for PPT here: Create an ADD-IN with TOOLBARS that run macros
http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00031_Create_an_ADD-IN_with_TOOLBARS_that_run_macros.htm

Comment: The code you've posted above won't work for a variety of reasons. Did you look at the link I suggested and base your code on that?

Comment: @ValerySaharov  Commandbars.Add isn't broken.Post the code you're actually using or create a simple example and post that.

Comment: I've helped all I can. Good luck, have fun, I'm done.

Answer (score 1):

Valery, you're much more likely to get help from people who give up their time for free if you show some respect instead of being rude and dismissive of contributors help. Now let's put that to one side.

One ribbon-based solution you could use to add a dynamic UI is to add a new tab, group and dynamicMenu control to the ribbon definition in the XML of your PPTM project (the hard coded part) and then programmatically and items to that menu via its getContent callback. You can also show/hide the tab/group/control under conditions you define via getVisible callbacks. It's not a simple two or three line code example so you WILL have to do some reading in order to implement this approach but this page included in Cindy's answer will help:

[Scroll down to "dynamicMenu"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12))

This is the XML you need to get started:

```
<menu xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
  <button id="dynaButton" label="Button" 
    onAction="OnAction" imageMso="FoxPro"/>
  <toggleButton id="dynaToggleButton" label="Toggle Button" 
    onAction="OnToggleAction" image="logo.bmp"/>
  <menuSeparator id="div2"/>
  <dynamicMenu id="subMenu" label="Sub Menu" getContent="GetSubContent" />
</menu>
```

And you then need to inject the UI code via the VBA callback sub GetSubContent.